# Switch case does not pick up the correct case when using is_numeric

Tags: php, switch-statement

So, i have the following switch case (i've only put 3 for this example, but there are more...).

```
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    $get_category = trim($_GET['cat']);

    switch ($get_category) {
        case is_numeric($get_category):
            echo 'is_numeric';
            // execute query
            break;
        case 'newest':
            echo 'newest';
            // execute query
            break;
        case '':
            echo 'empty';
            // execute query
            break;
    }
}
```

When my `$_GET['cat']` is empty, i'm getting `is_numeric` and i'm supposed to get `empty`.

I've tried looking at the $_GET['cat] array, and i get this:

```
Array
(
    [cat] => 
)
```

I've also checked the type and i get `string`:

```
echo gettype($get_category); // returns: string
```

I've also use an `if statement` to verify if it picks up `is numeric` but it doesn't, it picks up `string`

```
if (is_numeric($get_category)) {
    echo 'numeric';
} else {
    echo 'string';
}

// returns: string
```

So, why is it that my `switch` statement does not pick up the correct case?

Comment: `switch/case` is for matching exact values, use `if` for testing conditions.

Comment: In the case statement. is_numeric is returning a false. Then comparing an empty string to false. which is a true statement.

Comment: You could add the default case. Then you could do any special testing in that block.